# Batch script to look through text file and echo text if it contains a character

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that can look through a text file.
In the text file, there are rows of texts. I need to go through each row and if it contains the characters `\\`, then I want to echo that whole row.

I currently have the following, but it does not work. What happens is all the rows end up being echoed, instead of those that have `\\`.

```
for /f "delims=*" %%A in (list.txt) do (
    if NOT "%%A"=="%%A:\\=%" (
        echo %%A
    )
)
```

Anyone able to advise what happens?

Comment: `find "\" list.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319556/batch-script-to-look-through-text-file-and-echo-text-if-it-contains-a-character#comment79600028_46319556) of using `find` is for sure the easiest solution for your task. Anyway, I want to focus on your approach.

You cannot use [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) with [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variable references. You need to store `%%A` in a normal environment variable and apply sub-string replacement there. However, since you are within a block of code (`for` loop), you must use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). This is how it works:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=*" %%A in (list.txt) do (
    set "TEST=%%A"
    if NOT "!TEST!"=="!TEST:\\=!" (
        echo/!TEST!
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: i am not exactly sure how the find will work, i thought it is used to search for entire files.. in any case, your solution worked! i believe the difference is the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion part. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Find "\\"<"list.txt"` _that's it nothing else required!_

Comment: I realized that my output contains additional spacing. is there anyway I can enhance the command Find "\\"<"list.txt" to remove the spacing?

Comment: What do you mean by "additional spacing"? `find` does not remove anything, it just finds strings within lines of text...